# Javascript Concatenate dates and time together

Tags: javascript

I have this code which generates the current date + time in javascript:

```
    var date_variable = new Date();

    var year    = date_variable.getFullYear();
    var month   = date_variable.getMonth() + 1;
    var day     = date_variable.getDate();

    var hour    = date_variable.getHours();
    var minutes = date_variable.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date_variable.getSeconds();

    var full_date = year + month + day + hour + minutes + seconds;

    console.log(year);
    console.log(month);
    console.log(day);
    console.log(hour);
    console.log(minutes);
    console.log(seconds);
    console.log(full_date);
```

Everything in console displays fine, except when it comes to the `full_date` variable. This is what's displayed in console:

```
   2014
   8
   27
   10
   53
   10
   2122
```

My question is, why does the last output not combine my date + time into a single string?

Thanks

Comment: you're adding numbers together. So you get the sum of them.

Comment: If your project will work extensively with dates I recommend you having a look at http://momentjs.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the properties you are accessing return a `number`.  When you add them together with the `+` operator, you are just adding numbers together.

If you substitute the variables used in full date, it would look something like:

```
var full_date = 2014 + 8 + 26 + . . .
```

All you have to do is put a strings in the expression and you will get what you want.

In all honesty though, you should use `Date.toLocalDateString()` or `Date.toLocalTimeString()` if the format works for you.  You can read the documentation about them on [MDN's Date reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Oh yea, damn I forgot about that. Thanks a tone

Comment: you can do var full_date = '' + year + month + ...; The empty string will force the numbers into strings. (that's 2 single quote marks btw) Faster to type then trying to call toString on each value.

Comment: Yep, just found that answer a few min ago. Cheers for the help  :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the numbers with a string first.

```
var full_date = year +""+ month +""+ day +""+ hour +""+ minutes +""+ seconds;
```